# How to change tailwind animation by value?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to give the attribute animation-slide-right if the value is true, and the attribute animation-slide-left if the value is false.

However, with the exception of the initial rendering, when the value changes, the animation does not apply.

I hope the animation will be applied whenever the value changes.

You can see my situation here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gnlpbz?file=tailwind.config.js

Comment: See if this solves your problem:

```<span className={`w-6 h-6 bg-[#ffffff] absolute top-[3px] -translate-x-full rounded-full transition-all ${value ? 'left-[calc(100%-3px)]' : 'left-1/2'}`}/>```

Comment: @SarangaB In this case, it can be done with transition. I took the wrong example, but the border-radius and width keep changing. Updated situations is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gnlpbz?file=tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `tailwind.config.js` created a separate keyframe config for the `slide-left` instead of reversing the `slide-right` like the following

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        'slide-right': {
          '0%': {
            left: '0%',
          },
          '100%': {
            left: '100%',
          },
        },
        'slide-left': {
          '0%': {
            left: '100%',
          },
          '100%': {
            left: '0%',
          },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        'slide-right': 'slide-right 0.7s linear',
        'slide-left': 'slide-left 0.7s linear',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This seems to resolve the issue but I don't understand why your implementation didn't work either it seems to be doing the same thing as far as I can tell

Here is the updated config https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-tcxew6?file=tailwind.config.js

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll figure it out this way